# ARCore Geospatial API: what building is my camera pointed at?

Tags: android, geospatial, arcore, google-street-view

mobile developers!

I am trying to use the ARCore Geospatial APIs in order to determine the exact location (lat/long) or a street address my device is pointed at.
I'm using the Codelab Geospatial, it's working, giving me the lat/long, altitude, heading of my device, I can even add an anchor, but now trying to determine the location of what I'm looking at.

Google documentation is saying that I can retrieve any StreetView location but I couldn't find how to do that. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!